# Hint for a problem about symmetric operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is there any hint in order to prove that for a given real vector space $V$ and $T: V \to V$ such $T^{2}=T$ and $T T^{*}=T^{*}T$, then $T=T^{*}$.

I understand that I need to prove that $\left<T(v),w\right>=\left<v,T(w)\right>$ for every $v, w \in V$.

Comment: Hint: $T$ is a projection. Draw a picture to convince yourself it is orthogonal. Use this picture to decompose $v$ and $w$ into their parallel and orthogonal parts.

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$|Tx|^2=(x,T^*Tx)=(x,TT^*x)=|T^*x|^2$$
Use this to show that
$ T^*(1-T)=0$ and similarly
$T(1-T^*)=0$. From this you may deduce the result.